# Redux Toolkit cache holding duplicated data after RTK Query requests

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit, debouncing, rtk-query

I am working on a project for which I am trying to implement autocompletion through suggestions during typing: in practice, every new letter being typed corresponds to a new query against the app database (which is running locally).

The frontend tech stack is React Native, Expo and Redux Toolkit, therefore I am making the above requests via RTK Query.

Below is the AddressSearch component responsible for:

- receiving the user input
- rendering it,
- querying the database, passing the "debounced" user input
- displaying the suggestions retrieved from the database into a `Flatlist`

```js
const AddressSearch = () => {
  const styles = stylesFn();
  // string from the GUI, grows while typing
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  // string fed to the API, after 2s delay
  const [debouncedInput, setDebouncedInput] = useState("");
  // raw data as pulled from the API
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState();
  // RTKQ skip setting to avoid requesting the API too soon
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(true);

  let {
    data: rawSuggestions,
    isFetching,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetCarQuery(debouncedInput, { skip });

  // pass returned `data` to the JSX
  useEffect(() => {
    if (rawSuggestions) {
      setSuggestions(rawSuggestions);
    }
  }, [rawSuggestions]);

  const updateSearchedAddress = (text) => {
    text.length > 2 ? setSkip(false) : setSkip(true);
    // update the form GUI state
    setInput(text);
    // update the RTKQ state after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedInput(text);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {/* ... */}
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={true}
        showVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        data={suggestions ? suggestions.results : null}
        renderItem={({ item, index, separators }) => (
          <Pressable key={item.id}>
            <Text>
              {item.id} {item.make} {item.model} {item.version} {item.fuel}
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        )}
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </View>
  );
};

export default AddressSearch;
```

Upon executing a search, it is possible to get duplicated results as per following warning:

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `246`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

As far as I can tell, the above is due to firing multiple requests quickly combined with Redux caching results and not provididing [data deduplication](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/comparison#no-normalized-or-deduplicated-cache).

So, I tried to debounce the requests to avoid firing them too early, but I cannot find an effective way to do that.

Also, I believe that forcing re-queries (in order to replace the cache entirely) upon every keypress could solve the above issue but, being a JS beginner, I am not sure about how to do that.

Hence my question: how do I get rid of the above warning in an efficient manner, while minimizing the requests and keeping the `key` logic as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting data back from the server that just contains that key twice. RTK Query by default does not combine any data, it always replaces the old data, so that cannot be it.

Also, you **really** do not need that `useEffect` there. Just directly work with `data/rawSuggestions`. Your `useEffect` just adds another rerender. If you want to derive data from that, use `useMemo` instead.

Comment: dear @phry thanks for both hints!